# Replace method implementation when stubbing with mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, stubbing

I'm used to RSpec in which you can stub a method implementation with a block which is [evalueted lazily](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs/stub-with-substitute-implementation).

Now I'm working to a pull request for a project which uses Test::Unit and [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) as mocking library.

I need to be able to do something similar to the rspec example, i.e. replace a method implementation with a dynamic one which depends on object state, so I can not use static calls provided by mocha `#returns` method.

Is there any way to get the same functionality with mocha, I wasn't able to find any documentation on this?

I need to implement something similar to this (RSpec 2.14 syntax)

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    # original method I need to replace
  end

  def some_other_method
    :bar
  end

end

describe SomeController do

  before do
    controller.stub :authenticate do
      redirect_to root_path if some_other_method == :foo
    end
  end

  it 'should test something' do
    controller.stub(some_other_method: :foo)
    get :index
    response.should redirect_to root_path
  end

  it 'should test something else' do
    get :index
    response.should be_successful
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use `def` on the `controller` instance?

```
def controller.some_other_method
  :foo
end
```

Comment: I came to the same answer by myself while experimenting. Often simplest things are the most effective. The whole example is more complicated than the one I've posted however I can refactor the test to use this approach.

Comment: How to cleanup after this and restore the original definition?

Comment: You could either alias the old method and then restore it the other way round, or you could use refinements to make the change only in the current spec file. I woul however recommend using a different library if you can, one that supports dynamic stubs. For example http://rr.github.io/rr/ although i havent used it myself.

Comment: Mocks are not really meant to be used like this, here's a great article on the different types of test doubles: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html